# How to return dynamic columns from grouped values in SQL Server (Stored Procedure)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two cases very similar that I need to generate SPs.

In the first case I need a SQL able to return columns by the number of activities (dynamic if possible). I have to create columns by **ActivityId**.

**Case 1:**

> Grouping by **Date, count(ActivityId)**
>
> Returning columns: **Activity1, Activity2, Activity3**

**Table 1**

```
╔════════════╦══════════════╗
║ ActivityId ║ ActivityName ║
╠════════════╬══════════════╣
║          1 ║ Activity 1   ║
║          2 ║ Activity 2   ║
║          3 ║ Activity 3   ║
╚════════════╩══════════════╝
```

**Table 2**

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╗
║   Date    ║ ActivityId ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╣
║ 1/05/2015 ║          1 ║
║ 1/05/2015 ║          1 ║
║ 2/05/2015 ║          2 ║
║ 3/05/2015 ║          3 ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╝
```

**Query result**

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║   Date    ║ Activity1 ║ Activity2 ║ Activity3 ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ 1/05/2015 ║         2 ║         0 ║         0 ║
║ 2/05/2015 ║         0 ║         1 ║         0 ║
║ 3/05/2015 ║         0 ║         0 ║         1 ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

**Case 2:**

> In another scenario I will have to do exactly the same thing but instead of
>   Activities it will be a list of days in a month:

**Table 1**

```
╔════════════╦═══════════╦═══════╗
║    Date    ║ Account   ║ Value ║
╠════════════╬═══════════╬═══════╣
║ 30/05/2015 ║         1 ║    10 ║
║ 27/05/2015 ║         2 ║    40 ║
╚════════════╩═══════════╩═══════╝
```

**Query result:**

```
╔═════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ Account ║ 30/05/2015 ║ 29/05/2015 ║ 28/05/2015 ║ 27/05/2015 ║…each day in a month ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║       1 ║         10 ║          0 ║          0 ║          0 ║                     ║
║       2 ║          0 ║          0 ║          0 ║         40 ║                     ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Comment: [This should get you started](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: It was very helpful, I could use Pivot table to do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do it by using PIVOT command:

**Case 1**

```
select p.[Date], ISNULL([1],0)[Activity1], ISNULL([2],0)[Activity2], ISNULL([3],0)[Activity3], ISNULL([4],0)[Activity4], ISNULL([5],0)[Activity5], ISNULL([6],0)[Activity6] 
FROM
(
    SELECT CONVERT(date, [Date]) [Date], ActivityId, COUNT(*) Total
    from Activity
    group by convert(date, [Date]), ActivityId

) AS Tb

PIVOT
(
    SUM(Total)
    FOR ActivityId IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])
) p
order by convert(date, p.[Date])
```

Answer (score 2):

For Case 1 try this:

```
--Creating Test tables
create table #activity
(
    ActivityId TINYINT,
    ActivityName VARCHAR(20)
)

create table #date
(
    [Date] DATE,
    ActivityId TINYINT
)

INSERT INTO #activity VALUES(1,'Activity 1')
INSERT INTO #activity VALUES(2,'Activity 2')
INSERT INTO #activity VALUES(3,'Activity 3')

INSERT INTO #date VALUES('2015-05-01',1)
INSERT INTO #date VALUES('2015-05-01',1)
INSERT INTO #date VALUES('2015-05-02',2)
INSERT INTO #date VALUES('2015-05-03',3)


DECLARE @activities NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET  @activities = ''
SET  @stmt = ''

--Get List of Activities
SELECT  @activities = @activities + ',[' + ActivityName + ']'
FROM    #activity

SET @activities = RIGHT(@activities, LEN(@activities)-1) --Remove Leading Comma

--Build PIVOT Statement
SET @stmt = 'SELECT  [Date],' + @activities + '
            FROM    (SELECT d.[Date], a.ActivityName
                     FROM   #date d
                            INNER JOIN #activity a ON d.ActivityId = a.ActivityId) tab
                    PIVOT (COUNT(ActivityName) FOR ActivityName IN (' + @activities + ')) AS NumberOfActivities'

--Execute
EXEC sp_executesql @stmt

--CleanUp
DROP TABLE #activity
DROP TABLE #date
```

Comment: for case 2 you can take the same approach, just change the query inside the statement which is called "tab" in my example and instead of @activities string you can build a string which contrains the dates you want to display... Hope this was helpful!