# Write a query to count different kind of records in single line result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by, sql-server-2012

I have a table with 2 columns TimeStamp and ID in `MS SQLSERVER`

```
TimeStamp      ID
2015-05-20      1
2015-05-20      2
2015-05-20      1
2015-05-21      1
2015-05-21      2
2015-05-21      2
2015-05-21      1
```

My requirement is to calculate number of records for every Id according to date.

Requirement:

```
Date           No of records for Id=1           No. records for ID=2            Total
2015-05-20         2                                     1                        3
2015-05-21         2                                     2                        4
```

Please let me know how can i do this for other columns as well.

Thanks

Comment: Is it 2008 r2 or 2012? Don't you know what version of sql server are you working on? If you need both of them, go for the oldest one since it's solution will probably work for the newer as well. Also, read about Pivot

Comment: created a fiddle for people who want to test their solutions: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c28c/1

Comment: Generally you don't do this in the DB.  You'd do a count grouped by date & ID to get rows then get your reporting/consumer to work out how to present it.  Dynamic SQL can hurt performance and security.  Also this approach may cause you may run out of columns (as someone else said).  What's the destination of this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Pivot - can look like this:

```
SELECT  [TimeStamp], [1] AS [No of records for Id=1], [2] AS [No of records for Id=2], [1]+[2] AS Total
FROM    dbo.YourTable
        PIVOT
        (
            COUNT(ID) FOR ID IN ([1],[2])
        ) pvt
ORDER BY [TimeStamp]
```

Comment: What if id column value exceeds ?

Comment: then you have to take a look at building the statement dynamically! i answered this in another question. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295640/how-to-return-dynamic-columns-from-grouped-values-in-sql-server-stored-procedur/30297102#30297102

Answer (score 0):

I've got your answer using subqueries:

SQLFIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c28c/5

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.myts, 
                (SELECT COUNT(*)
                 FROM mytable t2
                 WHERE t2.myts = t1.myts
                 AND t2.id = 1) AS id_1_count,
                (SELECT COUNT(*)
                 FROM mytable t2
                 WHERE t2.myts = t1.myts
                 AND t2.id = 2) AS id_2_count,
                (SELECT COUNT(*)
                 FROM mytable t2
                 WHERE t2.myts = t1.myts) AS total
FROM mytable t1
```

If you add an id here though you would need another subquery

Comment: this will maybe show the correct result but it will end up in very bad performance...it's not readable code and not dynamic...

Comment: I'm not arguing with performance or dynamic but how is it not readable? if you put the indentation right it should be perfectly readable

Comment: maybe it's in the eye of the beholder ;-) Query design, new lines, lower case, upper case keywords, indentation,...  let's say this some kind of art - some like it and some not, everybody has his style and preferences

Answer (score 0):

For completion the Dynamic Way:

```
DECLARE @id_values NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET  @id_values = ''
SET  @stmt = ''

--Get List of ID's
SELECT  @id_values = @id_values + ',[' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR) + ']'
FROM    dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY ID

SET @id_values = RIGHT(@id_values, LEN(@id_values)-1) --Remove Leading Comma

--Build PIVOT Statement
SET @stmt = 'SELECT [TimeStamp],' + @id_values + ','+ REPLACE(@id_values,',','+') + ' AS Total
            FROM    dbo.YourTable
                    PIVOT
                    (
                        COUNT(ID) FOR ID IN (' + @id_values + ')
                    ) pvt
            ORDER BY [TimeStamp]'


--Execute
EXEC sp_executesql @stmt
```