# Querying a table on it self MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm puzzeling a little with a `SQL` query / `vTable` I want to make. We have a table that contains computers (virtual and physical):

```
CluserName  ComputerName  CoreCount
N/A         BackOffice1   2
cluster1    sqlServer     4
cluster1    webserver     2
cluster1    sqlServer2    6
cluster2    adServer      2
cluster2    adServer2     4
```

I would not like to pull a `vTable` that would give me something like this:

```
Cluster: cluster1, 12 (this is a summation of the cores in the
cluster) sqlServer, 4 webserver, 2 sqlServer2, 6 Cluster: cluster2, 6
adServer, 2 adServer2, 4
```

So my two questions is:

1. Is it stupid to do this via a `vTable`
2. If not is this an `INNER JOIN` or a nested query?

Thanks.

Comment: what version of sql are you using? sql server, mysql, oracle?

Comment: Title says it is MS Sql

Comment: I'm using MS SQL 2014

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f7fe/11/0

```
SELECT CluserName, SUM(CoreCount) AS CoreCount, 
SUM(CASE WHEN ComputerName = 'sqlServer' THEN CoreCount ELSE 0 END) AS sqlServer,
SUM(CASE WHEN ComputerName = 'webserver' THEN CoreCount ELSE 0 END) AS webserver,
SUM(CASE WHEN ComputerName = 'sqlServer2' THEN CoreCount ELSE 0 END) AS sqlServer2,
SUM(CASE WHEN ComputerName = 'asServer' THEN CoreCount ELSE 0 END) AS asServer
FROM table1
group by CluserName
```

**Update using dynamic query:**

This build a dynamic query getting the computer names from the table so when new computer names are added it should work.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c95d3/34

```
DECLARE @statement nvarchar(max)
SET @statement = 'SELECT CluserName, SUM(CoreCount) AS CoreCount, '
SELECT @statement = @statement + 
( SELECT distinct 'SUM(CASE WHEN COMPUTERName = ''' + ComputerName 
+ ''' THEN CoreCount ELSE 0 END) AS ' + ComputerName + ',' FROM table1 FOR XML PATH('') 
) 
+ ' '''' FROM table1 group by CluserName'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @statement
```

Comment: the only problem is that the computer names are note allways the same. So if the sames of the servers are changed, the calculation fails.

Comment: @FrederikKrogh You mean next day you could get a new computer named sqlServer4 and it gets added to this table?

Comment: @FrederikKrogh Updated the answer with a dynamic query.

Answer (score 0):

Group by `ROLLUP`:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      CluserName VARCHAR(20) ,
      ComputerName VARCHAR(20) ,
      CoreCount INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 'N/A', 'BackOffice1', 2 ),
        ( 'cluster1', 'sqlServer', 4 ),
        ( 'cluster1', 'webserver', 2 ),
        ( 'cluster1', 'sqlServer2', 6 ),
        ( 'cluster2', 'adServer', 2 ),
        ( 'cluster2', 'adServer2', 4 )


SELECT  CluserName , ComputerName, SUM(CoreCount) CoreCount
FROM    @t
GROUP BY ROLLUP(CluserName,ComputerName)
ORDER BY GROUPING(CluserName) DESC, CluserName, GROUPING(ComputerName) desc
```

Output:

```
CluserName  ComputerName    CoreCount
NULL        NULL            20
cluster1    NULL            12
cluster1    sqlServer       4
cluster1    sqlServer2      6
cluster1    webserver       2
cluster2    NULL            6
cluster2    adServer        2
cluster2    adServer2       4
N/A         NULL            2
N/A         BackOffice1     2
```

If you don't want the total row then:

```
SELECT  CluserName , ComputerName, SUM(CoreCount) CoreCount
FROM    @t
GROUP BY ROLLUP(CluserName,ComputerName)
HAVING CluserName IS NOT NULL OR ComputerName IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY GROUPING(CluserName) DESC, CluserName, GROUPING(ComputerName) desc
```

Output:

```
CluserName  ComputerName    CoreCount
cluster1    NULL            12
cluster1    sqlServer       4
cluster1    sqlServer2      6
cluster1    webserver       2
cluster2    NULL            6
cluster2    adServer        2
cluster2    adServer2       4
N/A         NULL            2
N/A         BackOffice1     2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Dynamic Pivot Statement as shown here:
[How to return dynamic columns from grouped values in SQL Server (Stored Procedure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295640/how-to-return-dynamic-columns-from-grouped-values-in-sql-server-stored-procedur)

in your case it would look like this i think - give it a try:

```
DECLARE @computernames NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @total NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET  @computernames = ''
SET  @stmt = ''

--Get List of Computers
SELECT  @computernames = @computernames + ',[' + ComputerName + ']'
FROM    yourtable
GROUP BY ComputerName

--Remove Leading Comma
SET @computernames = RIGHT(@computernames, LEN(@computernames)-1) 

--transform [adserver],[adserver2]  to ISNULL([adserver],0) + ISNULL([adserver2],0)
SET @total = 'ISNULL(' + REPLACE(@computernames,'],[','],0) + ISNULL([') + ',0)'


--Build PIVOT Statement
SET @stmt = 'SELECT [ClusterName],' + @computernames + ','+ @total + ' AS TotalCores
            FROM    yourtable
                    PIVOT
                    (
                        SUM(CoreCount) FOR ComputerName IN (' + @computernames + ')
                    ) pvt
            ORDER BY [ClusterName]'


--Execute
EXEC sp_executesql @stmt
```

The result will look like this:

```
ClusterName adServer adServer2 BackOffice1 sqlServer sqlServer2 webserver TotalCores
cluster1    NULL     NULL      NULL        4         6          2           12
cluster2    2        4         NULL        NULL      NULL       NULL        6
N/A         NULL     NULL      2           NULL      NULL       NULL        2
```

Comment: And it's dynamic in every way. It works even if you insert/delete /update ComputerNames or Clusters