# How to pivot the given structure to expected one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, pivot-table

I have queries results as in the image, similarly for 90 date's, so how to group object and make date's as columns and count to respective date's.

[image]

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Something wrong with your expected results? 201145-01-02?

Comment: You're probably looking for a dynamic pivot, or just a normal one if you have fixed number of dates

Comment: possible dublicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295640/how-to-return-dynamic-columns-from-grouped-values-in-sql-server-stored-procedur/30297102#30297102

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using a dynamic crosstab:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bd52e/1/0)

```
DECLARE @sql1 VARCHAR(4000) = ''
DECLARE @sql2 VARCHAR(4000) = ''
DECLARE @sql3 VARCHAR(4000) = ''

SELECT @sql1 = 
'SELECT
    [Object]' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql2 = @sql2 +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN [Date] = CAST(''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [Date], 112) + ''' AS DATE) THEN [count] END) AS ' + QUOTENAME([Date]) + CHAR(10)
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT [Date] FROM tbl
)t
ORDER BY [Date]

SELECT @sql3 = 
'FROM tbl
GROUP BY [Object]
ORDER BY [Object]'

PRINT(@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
EXEC (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
```

**RESULT**

```
| Object | 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-02 |
|--------|------------|------------|
|      1 |         10 |         34 |
|      2 |         20 |         46 |
|      3 |        130 |         78 |
|      4 |         40 |         89 |
|      5 |         55 |         45 |
```

---

This is the output of the `PRINT` command:

```
SELECT
    [Object]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN [Date] = CAST('20150101' AS DATE) THEN [count] END) AS [2015-01-01]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN [Date] = CAST('20150102' AS DATE) THEN [count] END) AS [2015-01-02]
FROM tbl
GROUP BY [Object]
ORDER BY [Object]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use  SQL Server  PIVOT relational operator

```
DECLARE   @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE   @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get unique values of pivot column  
SELECT   @PivotColumns= COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',','') + QUOTENAME([Date])
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Date] FROM [dbo].[PivotExample]) AS PivotExample



--Create the dynamic query with all the values for 
--pivot column at runtime
SET   @SQLQuery = 
    N'SELECT ObjectId, ' +   @PivotColumns + '
    FROM [dbo].[PivotExample] 
    PIVOT( SUM(COUNT) 
          FOR [Date] IN (' + @PivotColumns + ')) AS P'


EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```